# How to remove Google Drive document from only one folder?

Tags: google-drive

I have one document in *My Drive* which is located in three different folders. I want to keep the document in two of the folders and remove it from only one of the folders. I don't want to "move" the document to any folder, I just want to removed it from one of the three.

[Google help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375028?hl=en) says this can be done by doing the following:

> Here's how to add or remove something from a folder on Google Drive on the web:
>
> 1. Check the box next to the title of the item you want to add or remove.
> 2. Click the Folder icon above your list of items.
> 3. To remove something from a folder: deselect the folder where an item is currently stored.
>    Click Move.

I navigating to the folder I want to remove the document from (*Info Requested*) and see this:

[image]

I click the check mark but nothing happens. When this folder is selected it only gives me the option to *move* the document to the selected folder. It says, "You are removing items from two shared folders: "name1" and "name2"" Which I do not want to do.

I have many other documents I am trying to organize and want to find a simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 17):

1. Select the document and click "View Details" from the context menu.
2. Scroll down to where it says "Location" and it will list all the folders the document is currently in.
3. Click the "x" next to the folder you want it removed from.

That will remove it from a single folder while keeping it in all the other folders it was in.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The steps listed by @Jonathan work perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer!!!

Comment: Is there any way to do this for multiple files at once (for example, all documents in a specific folder that I want to "clean out?"

Answer (score 0):

So, the directions are wrong. You can't deselect the folder. If you only select the folder you want the document in, it will move it out of the folder you don't want it in. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To remove one of the three folders your document is in, use the Move operation and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking the folder you want to remove.

This applies also for changing folders of multiple files, for adding some folders and removing other folders etc.